# Converting Torchvision object detection models to CoreML

Tags: pytorch, coreml, torchvision, coremltools

Is there a demo/example on how to convert Torchvision object detection models to CoreML?

It's strange that CoreML documentation has tutorials for Torchvision [classification](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/convert-a-torchvision-model-from-pytorch) and [segmentation](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/pytorch-conversion-examples), but not for object detection. Is it because it's not possible?

I'm unsuccessfully trying to convert Torchvision object detection models to CoreML. I've tried converting `ssdlite320_mobilenet_v3_large`, `fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2` and `retinanet_resnet50_fpn_v2`, but errors like these always happen:

`images.7 defined in (%images.7 : __torch__.torchvision.models.detection.image_list.ImageList, %targets.31 : Dict(str, Tensor)[]? = prim::TupleUnpack(%396)\n)",`